# Что нужно сделать с репозиторием чтобы правильно выполнять задания?

Tags: git, github, репозиторий

Есть публичный репозиторий https://github.com/Fuse8/school2023
Там есть задания, которые я бы хотел самостоятельно попробовать выполнить, что мне для этого нужно сделать с репозиторием?
Я понимаю что оно уже закончилось, я просто хотел попрактиковаться.
Если я клонирую репозиторий, то по сути я коммиты буду отправлять на него же. Там написано создать приватный репозиторий, я создал, а что дальше? Мне этот публичный репозиторий нужно в свой приватный как то склонировать или что?

Comment: Там есть кнопка fork. Вот она-то вам и нужна. Создастся копия репозитория в вашем профиле.